# Python- If statements with random numbers not working

Tags: python, if-statement, random

I'm very new to programming and I'm trying to write a program in python 3.6 that generates a random number as an "answer" and then the computer has to guess that answer for x number of questions. To keep track of how many questions the computer guesses right, I created a variable called 'right' and if the computer's answer equals the guess, then add one to that variable. However, it does it everytime even if it's wrong. Sorry if this seems stupid, but thank you for your help

```
import random
def total(x, t):
        for i in range(t):
                cor = 0
                gue = 0
                n = 0
                right = 0
                def ans():
                         cor = random.randint(1,4)
                         print(cor, 'answer')
                def guess():
                         gue = random.randint(1,4)
                         print(gue, 'guess')
                while n <= x:
                         ans()
                         guess()
                         if cor == gue:
                                 right += 1
                         n += 1 
                print(right, n)
```

Comment: in the line `if cor == gue`, `cor` and `gue` are always zero so they are always equal. Changing these variables in the `ans()` and `guess()` functions only changes them inside that function. There are ways around this (such as declaring those variables nonlocal) but the best way is to return the values.

Comment: Thank you I took out the first part where I defined cor and gue as 0 and made them global inside ans() and guess(). It works now, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I tried to slightly modify your code by moving the `ans()` and `guess()` functions outside the `total(x,t)` function since they seem independent from each other. Previously `ans` and `guess` were generating `cor` and `gue` randomly but not returning their values to be used in the `if` statement which was always using the initial values of `0`. Now by saving the returned values as `cor = ans()` and `gue = guess()`, the initialised values of `0` for `cor` and `gue` are overwritten.

```
import random

def ans():
    cor = random.randint(1,4)
    print(cor, 'answer')
    return cor

def guess():
    gue = random.randint(1,4)
    print(gue, 'guess')
    return gue

def total(x, t):
    for i in range(t):
        cor = 0
        gue = 0
        n = 0
        right = 0
        while n <= x:
            cor = ans()
            gue = guess()
            if cor == gue:
                     right += 1
            n += 1 
    print(right, n)


print (total(2,3))
```

**Output**

```
1 answer
2 guess
3 answer
4 guess
1 answer
4 guess
0 3
3 answer
2 guess
1 answer
4 guess
3 answer
2 guess
0 3
2 answer
2 guess
2 answer
3 guess
3 answer
4 guess
1 3
```

Comment: Thanks, I moved them outside and it works perfectly now. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Up vote answers which you like in order to appreciate the time/efforts of those who helped you

Comment: I don't have high enough reputation for it to show :(

Answer (score 0):

Nesting functions like `ans` and `guess` can be useful but I'd steer clear of it while beginning programming. It makes your program harder to understand.

Here's my stab at what you are trying to do (if I've understood correctly!)

```
import random

# Play number_of_games_to_play of the number guessing game allowing a maximum of max_guesses per game played.
def play(number_of_games_to_play, max_guesses):
    num_games = 0
    guessed_right = 0
    while num_games < number_of_games_to_play:
        if guess_number(max_guesses):
            guessed_right += 1
        num_games += 1
    print('\n\nI played', num_games, 'games and guessed right', guessed_right, 'times')

# Generate a random number, try and guess it up to max_guesses times. Returns whether the number was guessed correctly or not.
def guess_number(max_guesses):
    answer = random.randint(1, 4)
    print('\n\nPlaying guess_number. The right answer is', answer)
    num_guesses = 0
    while num_guesses < max_guesses:
        guess = random.randint(1, 4)
        print('The computer guesses', guess)
        if guess == answer:
            print('That is right!')
            return True
        else:
            print('That is wrong')
        num_guesses += 1
    return False

play(number_of_games_to_play = 5, max_guesses = 4)
```

Comment: Sorry I made it unclear, what I was trying to do was something like a multiple choice test and see how many questions the computer could guess right. X was the number of questions and T was how many times the computer simulated a test. Thank you for your help, this was an interesting variation

Answer (score 0):

I think the you are having problems with the scope of the variables: `cor` and `gue` inside the functions are different from those outside them. Your functions are not changing the values of `cor` and `gue`, they are creating two new variables (named also `cor` and `gue`) that live only within them. For that reason, `cor` and `gue` are always 0, the condition in the if statement is always true, and you increment `rigth` every time.
To solve this issue, you could pass the variables as parameters to the functions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from variable scope. The variable core defined in method ans is different from variable core initalized in the for loop.
A better way is to do:

import random

```
def ans():
    c = random.randint(1, 4)
    return c


def guess():
    g = random.randint(1, 4)
    return g


def total(x, t):
    for i in range(t):
        n = 0
        right = 0
        while n <= x:
            cor = ans()
            gue = guess()
            if (cor == gue):
                right += 1
            print("Answer: %6d Guess: %6d Right: %d" % (cor, gue, right))
            n += 1
        print(right, n)
```

Comment: Thank you this looks much better than my original! I'm still learning and I appreciate the help